# Is an iisreset required after changing an application's App Pool?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6, application-pools

With IIS6, is it necessary to restart IIS if I change an application's Application Pool? I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but it would be great if someone could confirm this, and possibly include a link to some documentation.

Comment: Could someone please confirm whether IIS Reseet is required if identity is changed? Somewhere I read logon session,not sure what this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the app pool without restarting IIS and didn't have any problems, so the answer seems to be yes. The last sentence of [this Microsoft link](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/67e39bd8-317e-4cf6-b675-6431d4425248.mspx?mfr=true) states that "you can assign applications to another application pool while the server is running."